# pygame not updating the screen and enemy AI moving past player though conditons aren't met

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pygame

This is my script, everything works about it, the character can move around when the `wasd` keys are hit and the alien follows the player, however the alien moves in a beeling towards the player but if the player moves the alien will just move right past the player even though his position does not meet the conditions i set, the alien will only get back on course when the player hits a key.

```
import pygame, sys, random, time, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

bifl = 'screeing.jpg'
milf = 'char_fowed_walk1.png'
alien = 'alien_1.png'

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
background = pygame.image.load(bifl).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(milf).convert_alpha()
nPc = pygame.image.load(alien).convert_alpha()

x, y = 0, 0
movex, movey = 0, 0

z, w = random.randint(10, 480), random.randint(10, 640)
movexz, movew = 0, 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                movey = - 0.3
            elif event.key == K_s:
                movey = + 0.3
            elif event.key == K_a:
                movex = - 0.3
            elif event.key == K_d:
                movex = + 0.3

        if event.type == KEYUP:
             if event.key == K_w:
                movey = 0
             elif event.key == K_s:
                movey = 0
             elif event.key == K_a:
                movex = 0
             elif event.key == K_d:
                movex = 0

        if w < x:
            movew =+ 0.2
        if w > x:
            movew =- 0.2
        if z < y:
            movez =+ 0.2
        if z > y:
            movez =- 0.2

    x += movex
    y += movey
    w += movew
    z += movez
    print(x, y)






    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x, y))
    screen.blit(nPc, (w, z))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only updates the alien movement direction when some `event` takes place, so it will always wait for some user action before it can "turn around".

If you get the alien "AI" update out of the inner loop, everything should get back to normal

```
    if w < x:
        movew =+ 0.2
    if w > x:
        movew =- 0.2
    if z < y:
        movez =+ 0.2
    if z > y:
        movez =- 0.2

x += movex
y += movey
w += movew
z += movez
```

should look like

```
if w < x:
    movew =+ 0.2
if w > x:
    movew =- 0.2
if z < y:
    movez =+ 0.2
if z > y:
    movez =- 0.2

x += movex
y += movey
w += movew
z += movez
```